# cant connect to the bluetooth of raspberry pi3

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I have been working trying to send files from raspberry pi 3 to my phone via bluetooth. I followed instructables but it didnt work for me... I was able to install obexftp, however i can't connect to the phone. Pairing was successful but when i'm trying to connect the phone to raspberry pi, it gives this error 
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
What i have to do to transfer the files successfully 
PS: this is the first time i am working on bluetooth related issues

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any source code involved?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you very much for replying...i followed the steps given on this blog [link](http://david-raspberry-pi.blogspot.in/2013/03/send-image-from-raspberry-pi-via.html)

Comment: ....and you did exactly what? Without knowing what you did we cannot help

Comment: @NicoHaase yeah...I understood that code and was able to solve that...Thanks a lot